# Probability Density Function in layman terms

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know that PDF of a Random Variable (RV) helps in specifying the probability that the RV lies in a particular interval (for simplicity, let us assume that it is one-dimensional), and that, if it exists, it is the derivative of the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF). 
What I am not able to understand is, how do I explain it in simple language. Like, for CDF at a point $x$, we can say it gives the probability that the RV lies below $x$. What about the case of PDF? Is it possible to explain it independent of CDF?

Comment: I liked to think of it as a *density* function, as opposed to the *mass* function in case of a discrete RV. To get the *mass* of the probability from the probability *density*, you need to multiply it with volume (which is multiplying it with the variable range; i.e. the dx part in the integral)

Answer (score 0):

You can say that the value of PDF at a point $x$ is the "density" in the following sense: Given a small number $\epsilon >0$, consider the probability that your random variable takes values inside $[x - \epsilon , x + \epsilon]$ (i.e. does not deviate by more than $\epsilon$ from $x$), and divide this by $2 \epsilon$, the size of the interval. Then as $\epsilon$ becomes smaller and smaller, you are getting closer and closer to the value of the PDF at the point $x$.

---

So, the probability that the random outcome does not deviate by more than $1/1000$ from $x$ is roughly $PDF (x) \cdot 2/1000$. To formalize this "getting closer and closer", one has the notion of a limit.